# Vertx POST request body is `null` after using validator

Tags: java, vert.x

I created a simple `Vertx` web verticle which has a `POST` API. Following is the code:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) throws Exception {

    DatabindCodec.mapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.post("/demo")
      .handler(BodyHandler.create())
      .handler(rc -> {
        try {
          this.greet(rc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });

    HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
    httpServer.requestHandler(router).listen(8888, http -> {
      if (http.succeeded()) {
        startPromise.complete();
        System.out.println("HTTP server started on port 8888");
      } else {
        startPromise.fail(http.cause());
      }
    });


  }

  private void greet(RoutingContext routingContext) throws IOException {
    Person person = routingContext.body().asPojo(Person.class);
    try {
      boolean canSerializeResponse = DatabindCodec.mapper().canDeserialize(ReferenceType.constructUnsafe(PersonGreetMessage.class));
      routingContext.response().send(DatabindCodec.mapper().writerFor(PersonGreetMessage.class).writeValueAsString(new PersonGreetMessage(person, "Namaste")));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception");
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I proceeded to add request validation to make sure that request body matches the schema defined by me.

I first built a `SchemaParser` and defined a `Schema`

```
    SchemaParser parser = SchemaParser.createDraft7SchemaParser(
      SchemaRouter.create(vertx, new SchemaRouterOptions())
    );

    ObjectSchemaBuilder objectSchemaBuilder = objectSchema();

    ObjectSchemaBuilder addressSchemaBuilder = objectSchema();
    addressSchemaBuilder.requiredProperty("state", stringSchema());
    addressSchemaBuilder.optionalProperty("city", stringSchema());
    addressSchemaBuilder.optionalProperty("houseNumber", intSchema());
    addressSchemaBuilder.alias("addressSchema");
    addressSchemaBuilder.build(parser);

    objectSchemaBuilder.requiredProperty("name", stringSchema());
    objectSchemaBuilder.optionalProperty("address", refToAlias("addressSchema"));
    objectSchemaBuilder.build(parser);
```

then I changed the `router` to include the validation

```
  Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.post("/demo")
      .handler(ValidationHandlerBuilder.create(parser)
        .body(Bodies.json(objectSchemaBuilder))
        .build())
      .handler(rc -> {
        try {
          this.greet(rc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
```

And the actual method to generate the `Response`

```
private void greet(RoutingContext routingContext) throws IOException {
    RequestParameters requestParameters = routingContext.get(ValidationHandler.REQUEST_CONTEXT_KEY);
    JsonObject body = requestParameters.body().getJsonObject();
    Person person = DatabindCodec.mapper().readValue(body.toString(), Person.class);
    try {
      boolean canSerializeResponse = DatabindCodec.mapper().canDeserialize(ReferenceType.constructUnsafe(PersonGreetMessage.class));
      routingContext.response().send(DatabindCodec.mapper().writerFor(PersonGreetMessage.class).writeValueAsString(new PersonGreetMessage(person, "Namaste")));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      System.out.println("Exception");
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

I now get an exception like the following:

```
io.vertx.ext.web.validation.BodyProcessorException: [Bad Request] Body application/json parsing error: Null body
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.BodyProcessorException.createParsingError(BodyProcessorException.java:52)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.impl.body.JsonBodyProcessorImpl.process(JsonBodyProcessorImpl.java:33)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.impl.ValidationHandlerImpl.validateBody(ValidationHandlerImpl.java:247)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.impl.ValidationHandlerImpl.handle(ValidationHandlerImpl.java:143)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.impl.ValidationHandlerImpl.handle(ValidationHandlerImpl.java:18)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:68)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:67)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:30)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:55)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:158)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:145)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: io.vertx.ext.web.validation.MalformedValueException: Null body
    at io.vertx.ext.web.validation.impl.body.JsonBodyProcessorImpl.process(JsonBodyProcessorImpl.java:34)
    ... 52 more

Caused by: io.vertx.ext.web.validation.MalformedValueException: Null body
```

On debugging I found out that the following check in the `JsonBodyProcessorImpl` was failing

```
Buffer body = requestContext.body().buffer();
      if (body == null) {
        throw BodyProcessorException.createParsingError(
          requestContext.request().getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE),
          new MalformedValueException("Null body")
        );
      }
```

I have not been able to identify what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

> .handler(new BodyHandlerImpl())

```
router.post("/demo")
      .handler(new BodyHandlerImpl())
      .handler(ValidationHandlerBuilder.create(parser)
        .body(Bodies.json(objectSchemaBuilder))
          .body(Bodies.formUrlEncoded(objectSchemaBuilder))
        .build())
      .handler(rc -> {
        try {
          this.greet(rc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      });
```